# Conditional insert returning option of inserted row in Slick

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I am trying to create a conditional insert into a table with responses for an event. The event *may* have a limit on how many responses/attendees it can support so to prevent overbooking I want to check the status before I insert a new response.

The tables match the database models I have (IDs are generated by DB/auto inc):

```
case class Event(id: Option[Int], name: String, limitedCapacity: Option[Int])
case class Response(id: Option[Int], eventId: Int, email: String)
```

I have constructed a SQL statement that describes my conditional insert (eg, only insert if event has no limited capacity or if number of responses are less than the limit) that looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO responses(eventId, email)
SELECT :eventId, :email
    FROM events
    WHERE id = :eventId
    AND (limitedCapacity IS NULL
        OR (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM responses WHERE eventId = :eventId) < limitedCapacity);
```

but I don't know how to translate that into Slick DSL that also returns the inserted row. I am using PostgreSQL so I know return-row-on-insert is possible for normal insertions at least.

Here is some code that shows what I am after but I want this as a single transaction:

```
def create(response: Response): Future[Option[Response]] = {
  val event = db.run(events.filter(_.id === response.eventId).result.head)
  if (event.limitedCapacity.isEmpty) {
    db.run((responses returning responses) += response).map(Some(_))
  }
  else {
    val responseCount = db.run(responses.filter(_.eventId === response.id).length.result)
    if (responseCount < event.limitedCapacity.get) {
      db.run((responses returning responses) += response).map(Some(_))
    }
    else {
      Future.sucessful(None)
    }
  }
}
```

If it is not possible to return the inserted row that is fine but I need some kind of confirmation of the insertion at least.

Comment: Your problem is not just with Slick. You need to break this down into two parts. Part 1 - How to solve this requirement with your database in plain SQL. Part 2 - How to write that SQL with Slick. Part 2 is actaully not that important as you can even write perform SQL queries with Slick. And in worst case, you can just grab the underlying jdbc connection object and do things with all the low level power of jdbc. Most important is the Part 1. I will suggest that you post a question with your requirement and current SQL solution with SQL tag to get the Part 1 fixed.

Comment: Hm true, I will do that, one problem at a time! Thanks for the input!

Comment: Seems like this was easier than I thought, I just had to add ````RETURNING *``` before the closing semicolon to get the inserted row or an empty set if none were inserted. Now I am left with the problem of mapping the result to a Scala type. Is there a way to reuse the mappings I created in the table definition? The GetResult mapper feels a bit tacky since it won't map java.util.UUID and java.time.Instant for example